# pyspark; Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am trying to configure spark with hive meta store, to access hive tables from spark.

When i moved hive.site.xml to spark_home/conf i am getting errors. in spark when i tried to read data from hive tables. and the same error when i tried to execute simple select query in hive shell.

error i am getting is below.

for hive

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

for spark

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
```

Comment: I guess there is a 200-line error stack displayed below that generic error message. That's where you will find the exact problem.

Comment: And if a Hive client cannot connect to its own Metastore, then it is not a Spark problem. Either your `hiive-site.xml` is screwed, or the Metastore service is down _(if you are indeed running a global service, not the "embedded-in-each-client" mode)_, or the back-end database is down _(if you are indeed using a real database and not a Derby mock-up)_, etc